# How to show WebApi OAuth token endpoint in Swagger

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-identity, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

I've created a new Web Api project, added Asp.Net Identity and configured OAuth like so:

```
OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
{
    TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
    Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
    AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
    AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
    AllowInsecureHttp = true
};
```

This all works fine, I can call the /Token endpoint and get a bearer token back.

The problem is that this is not discoverable in Swagger I assume because it's not on a controller and therefore has no xml documentation generated for it.

Does anyone know of a way to display this login endpoint in my Swagger docs?

Thanks.

Also, i should've said that the Swagger documentation is working with all my controllers, it's just that I'm missing this one obvious method - how to login.

Comment: I don't know if this [Link](http://bitoftech.net/2014/08/25/asp-net-web-api-documentation-using-swagger/) is going to help or not but it will also explains how to create an XML if there isn't any one

Comment: Thanks, it's actually one of the articles i followed to setup Swagger.

Comment: You mention Swashbuckle in your tags, have you looked at the "Describing Security/Authorization Schemes" section of https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/README.md ?

Comment: Yes via swashbuckle - i've configured swagger for oauth implicit workflow, and this enables the swagger UI to perform post/get requests etc. I don't believe this configuration creates any api documentation to do with the token endpoint though.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

ApiExplorer won't be automatically generating any info for your endpoint so you'll need to add a custom DocumentFilter in order to manually describe the token endpoint.

There's an example of this at https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/issues/332 :

```
class AuthTokenOperation : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        swaggerDoc.paths.Add("/auth/token", new PathItem
        {
            post = new Operation
            {
                tags = new List<string> { "Auth" },
                consumes = new List<string>
                {
                    "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                },
                parameters = new List<Parameter> {
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "grant_type",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "username",
                        required = false,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "password",
                        required = false,
                        @in = "formData"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

httpConfig.EnableSwagger(c =>
{
    c.DocumentFilter<AuthTokenOperation>();
});
```

Comment: where do we need to put this class in order for the HelpPage generator to create the correct html ?

Comment: @EeKay: most likely in your SwaggerConfig.cs - it's the last part in the code example above (httpConfig.EnableSwagger(...))

Comment: Is there a way to then mark the password field so when input in the Try It section it shows ******* rather than the password?

Comment: OK found it - set the format = "password" on the Parameter object.  Thanks.

Comment: DocumentFilter is not recognised - is there a using or something needed ?

Comment: @user230910: Yes, it's using Swashbuckle.Swagger

Comment: This was a nice way to do the configuration, until they removed both Consumes and formData from OpenApiOperation classes.

Answer (score 8):

If anyone wondered how to add a response body to this operation, here's updated Ruaidhri's code:

```
class AuthTokenOperation : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        swaggerDoc.paths.Add("/token", new PathItem
        {
            post = new Operation
            {
                tags = new List<string> { "Auth" },
                consumes = new List<string>
                    {
                        "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
                    },
                parameters = new List<Parameter> {
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "grant_type",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "username",
                        required = false,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "password",
                        required = false,
                        @in = "formData"
                    }
                },
                responses = new Dictionary<string, Response>()
                {
                    {
                        "200",
                        new Response {schema = schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(typeof(OAuthTokenResponse))}
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}

class OAuthTokenResponse
{
    [JsonProperty("access_token")]
    public string AccessToken { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("token_type")]
    public string TokenType { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("expires_in")]
    public long ExpiresIn { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("userName")]
    public string Username { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(".issued")]
    public DateTime Issued { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(".expires")]
    public DateTime Expires { get; set; }
}
```