# How to customize swagger requests in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, swashbuckle, swagger-codegen

I have Swagger setup for an ASP.NET Core 2 MVC API application. I'm using OpenIddict for OAuth but want to customize how the request and responses appear on the documentation.

Since the method in the controller takes an `OpenIdConnectRequest`, the generated default output looks like so:

[image]

... and it just goes on and on.

This is a far cry from the neat JSON required for a client to consume since the middleware does a bunch of work inbetween the client and the controller method.

How do I change how Swagger represents these? I am already using a hack to massage the responses via a custom, private type for token responses, so any help on how to use that would also be appreciated. I have tried to use the `SwaggerGenOptions.MapType<>` function as the documentation claims that tells Swagger how to map a type to a custom output. Unfortunately, I've not gotten the Swagger output to reflect anything I've done with `.MapType<>`.

To be clear, these aren't models I control so I can't decorate the members myself.

Note that this is different from [How to show WebApi OAuth token endpoint in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164117/how-to-show-webapi-oauth-token-endpoint-in-swagger). My controller action is discovered fine. Unfortunately, I'm thinking it may be easier to filter it out and use that as another work around to define it manually but I'd rather not if possible.

Comment: Look into swashbuckle *iDocumentFilter* with that you can manipulate the final swagger json.