# How to add multiple actions to Swashbuckle Document Path pointing to one endpoint?

Tags: asp.net, oauth, swagger, owin, swashbuckle

I try to describe my asp.net Web API OAuth endpoint in swagger using Swashbuckle 5.6.0 and tried this solution:

[How to show WebApi OAuth token endpoint in Swagger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164117/how-to-show-webapi-oauth-token-endpoint-in-swagger)

My problem is, that the URL of receiving an access token and getting a new one by refresh token is the same in asp.net OAuth Authorization Server.
Adding the second URL to the Swagger Document Path fails due to the fact, that "paths" is a `IDictionary<string, PathItem>`.

```
public class AuthTokenOperation : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        // get the Token Endpoint from Config
        var endpoint = Helpers.GetAppSetting("TokenEndPoint");

        // Access Token
        swaggerDoc.paths.Add(endpoint, new PathItem
        {
            post = new Operation
            {
                tags = new List<string> { "AccessToken" },
                consumes = new string[] { "application/x-www-form-url-encoded" },
                produces = new string[] { "application/json" },
                parameters = new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "username",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "password",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "grant_type",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_id",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_secret",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        // Refresh Token
        swaggerDoc.paths.Add(endpoint, new PathItem
        {
            post = new Operation
            {
                tags = new List<string> { "AccessToken" },
                consumes = new string[] { "application/x-www-form-url-encoded" },
                produces = new string[] { "application/json" },
                parameters = new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "grant_type",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_id",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_secret",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "refresh_token",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Is there any possibility to describe two api methods pointing to the same endpoint, just using diffrent parameters?

Like shown here: https://api.gettyimages.com/swagger/ui/index#!/OAuth

Comment: Yes - I get an exception, that an element with that key has already been added to the collection:

Because:



`// Access Token`
`swaggerDoc.paths.Add(endpoint, new PathItem`
`{`
` // ... ... ...`
`}`

and

`// Refresh Token`
`swaggerDoc.paths.Add(endpoint, new PathItem`
`{`
`// ... ... ...`
`}`

point to the same endpoint. But I can't change them because ther're implemented in asp.net Identity.

Comment: I see the problem paths is a dictionary: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle/blob/master/Swashbuckle.Core/Swagger/SwaggerDocument.cs#L23 that would not allow duplicate keys....  I'm looking at the gettyimages, let's see what we can do

Comment: sorry - didn't help :(

Comment: I will test it today and keep you updated

Comment: it works now - seems to be a little "hacked" but it works  :)
I will provide the solution as seperate answer later.

Comment: And by the way there is nothing "hacked" about it, IF you want to use swagger properly we must follow the Open Api Specs: https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#specification, and the paths must be unique, The only hack is what GettyImages is doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The paths is a dictionary in swashbuckle:

```
  public class SwaggerDocument
  {
    public readonly string swagger = "2.0";
    public Info info;
    ...

    public IDictionary<string, PathItem> paths;
    ...
  }
```

that is why the exception "key has already been added to the collection"

On swagger we follow the Open Api Specification, and that path is a patterned field:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#patterned-fields

And they clearly state that duplicates is a no no for those patterned fields:

> Patterned fields can have multiple occurrences as long as each has a unique name.

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md#specification

---

The best option is to append something meaningless (like hash) to the endpoints to make them different, it could be something like:

```
swaggerDoc.paths.Add(endpoint + "#Access", new PathItem ...
swaggerDoc.paths.Add(endpoint + "#Refresh", new PathItem ...
```

---

How are the guys at gettyimages getting around that?

Here are some interesting findings

- Their swagger json does not have those `/oauth2/token` paths
  you can double check directly here: 
  https://api.gettyimages.com/swagger/docs/3
- Here is how their swagger json looks like in the latest version of the swagger-ui:
  http://petstore.swagger.io/?defaultModelsExpandDepth=0&docExpansion=none&url=https://api.gettyimages.com/swagger/docs/3

The version of swagger-ui they are using at gettyimages is heavily customized, I think they are injecting additional paths using JS
https://api.gettyimages.com/swagger/ui/ext/GettyImages-Resources-OAuthGrant-js

You can do that too, it will be a lot more work than just appending something to the endpoints

Answer (score 4):

Finally the hint "adding something meaningless" worked for our use case.

I additionally added a new model class `AuthServerResponseModel`, where the response of the auth request is mapped in.

```
public class AuthServerResponseModel
{
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string refresh_token { get; set; }
    public string audience { get; set; }
}
```

To make this object be known in Swagger, the class has to be added to the `SchemaRegistry`.

After that I could use the "@ref" tag in the response schema to declare the response type of my auth request.

```
public class AuthTokenOperation : IDocumentFilter
{
    public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
    {
        schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(typeof(AuthServerResponseModel));            

        // get the Token Endpoint from Config
        string endpoint = "URL-To-The-OAuth-Endpoint";

        // Access Token
        swaggerDoc.paths.Add(endpoint + "#AccessToken", new PathItem
        {
            post = new Operation
            {
                operationId = "AccessToken",
                tags = new List<string> { "Token" },
                consumes = new string[] { "application/x-www-form-url-encoded" },
                produces = new string[] { "application/json" },
                parameters = new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "username",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "password",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "grant_type",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_id",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_secret",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "DeviceId",
                        required = false,
                        @in = "formData"
                    }
                },
                responses = new Dictionary<string, Response>()
                {
                    { "200", new Response() { description = "Ok", schema = new Schema() { type = "object", @ref = "#/definitions/AuthServerResponseModel" } } },
                    { "400", new Response() { description = "BadRequest" } },
                    { "404", new Response() { description = "NotFound" } }
                }
            }
        });

        // Refresh Token
        swaggerDoc.paths.Add(endpoint + "#RefreshToken", new PathItem
        {
            post = new Operation
            {
                operationId = "RefreshToken",
                tags = new List<string> { "Token" },
                consumes = new string[] { "application/x-www-form-url-encoded" },
                produces = new string[] { "application/json" },
                parameters = new List<Parameter>
                {
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "grant_type",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_id",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "client_secret",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    },
                    new Parameter
                    {
                        type = "string",
                        name = "refresh_token",
                        required = true,
                        @in = "formData"
                    }
                },
                responses = new Dictionary<string, Response>()
                {
                    { "200", new Response() { description = "Ok", schema = new Schema() { type = "object", @ref = "#/definitions/AuthServerResponseModel"  } } },
                    { "400", new Response() { description = "BadRequest" } },
                    { "404", new Response() { description = "NotFound" } }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Automatic Client generation using Swagger Codegen works well now.

Comment: I see why your comment of ` seems to be a little "hacked" ` that DummyTextForSwagger is definitely a fat hack, ... look into  `schemaRegistry.GetOrRegister(`

Comment: Better, but still you can improve the repetitive code instantiating parameters