# add authentification UI to swagger

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api, swagger-ui

I have a C# ASP.NET Web API application with token, based authentication
The implementataion of authentication is in startup.cs  as follows

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Enable CORS (cross origin resource sharing) for making request using browser from different domains
        app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

        OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions options = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            AllowInsecureHttp = true,
            //The Path For generating the Toekn
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/token"),
            //Setting the Token Expired Time (24 hours)
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
            //MyAuthorizationServerProvider class will validate the user credentials
            Provider = new MyAuthorizationServerProvider()
        };
        //Token Generations
        app.UseOAuthAuthorizationServer(options);
        app.UseOAuthBearerAuthentication(new OAuthBearerAuthenticationOptions());

        HttpConfiguration config = new HttpConfiguration();
        WebApiConfig.Register(config);
    }
}
```

The definition of authentification is done in the follwing class

```
public class MyAuthorizationServerProvider : OAuthAuthorizationServerProvider
{
    public override async Task ValidateClientAuthentication(OAuthValidateClientAuthenticationContext context)
    {
        context.Validated();
    }
    public override async Task GrantResourceOwnerCredentials(OAuthGrantResourceOwnerCredentialsContext context)
    {
        using (UserMasterRepository _repo = new UserMasterRepository())
        {
            var user = _repo.ValidateUser(context.UserName, context.Password);
            if (user == null)
            {
                context.SetError("invalid_grant", "Provided username and password is incorrect");
                return;
            }
            var identity = new ClaimsIdentity(context.Options.AuthenticationType);
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, user.UserRoles));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName));
            identity.AddClaim(new Claim("Email", user.UserEmailID));
            context.Validated(identity);
        }
    }
}
```

I have added Swagger, to the application, it is working well: it is showing all the methods I implemented in the webapi application ***EXCEPT the authentication UI***
I tested the application with PostMan, in which I can get the token after filling the user and password
I want to do the same in SWAGGER: add a UI from which I can get a token after filling login/password

**How can I do that ?**

After posting the question, I found [a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32164117/how-to-show-webapi-oauth-token-endpoint-in-swagger) 
which I implemented in **Swaggerconfig.cs** file
but I'm getting this error "swaggerUiconfig does not contain a definition for 
DocumentFilter
I added

```
class AuthTokenOperation : IDocumentFilter
    {
        public void Apply(SwaggerDocument swaggerDoc, SchemaRegistry schemaRegistry, IApiExplorer apiExplorer)
        {
            swaggerDoc.paths.Add("/api/token", new PathItem
            {
                post = new Operation
                {
                    tags = new System.Collections.Generic.List<string> { "Auth" },
                    consumes = new List<string>
            {
                "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
            },
                    parameters = new List<Parameter> {
                new Parameter
                {
                    type = "string",
                    name = "grant_type",
                    required = true,
                    @in = "formData"
                },
                new Parameter
                {
                    type = "string",
                    name = "username",
                    required = false,
                    @in = "formData"
                },
                new Parameter
                {
                    type = "string",
                    name = "password",
                    required = false,
                    @in = "formData"
                }
            }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

but calling c.DocumentFilter(); is not accepted
it seems that there is a version conflict with DocumentFilter
How can I fix it ?